# Is the `addmultisignature` API call dependent on order of public keys in the array? Or is it lexicographically sorted?

Tags: bitcoin-core, api, multi-signature, public-key, p2sh

Say Alice and Bob are part of a partnership business that accepts Bitcoin. They store all their main funds in cold storage until the end of 3 months, when they cash out and use a new address. This cold storage is in a single address.

Both Alice and Bob have full nodes, running Bitcoin Core. They use the console feature to generate a 2-of-2 P2SH multisig address, using `addmultisignature`.

They exchange each other's public keys, and input them as arguments.

If Alice used the following syntax:

`addmultisignature 2 '[<alice's key>,<bob's key>]'`

and Bob used:

`addmultisignature 2 '[<bob's key>,<alice's key>]'`

Will they end up with the script hash and address?

*Follow up questions:*

Can you give certain keys more "weighting" by specifying them more than once?

Does the same logic apply to SegWit (P2WSH) multisigs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the `addmultisignature` API call dependent on order of public keys in the array? Or is it lexicographically sorted?

Yes. It is not sorted according to [BIP67](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0067.mediawiki) automatically.

How did I confirm?

I used the below command in bitcoin core:

```
addmultisigaddress 2 "[\"0318370919cfceb3d260081eeca3cae19f941eec321f597c48a64839178ea1e3e0\",\"03e783b8cf0474f732cc5d89cc893c25ab8a487785eb541a3ba0b26cfdd38c5c19\",\"02667b6e09a4a82b12cc8e5611373f28673f2cdd2e42b2f7e89825ec82b7f9b054\"]"
```

to get the multisig address details:

```
{
  "address": "tb1qlfu3fy8apmm4j73kzlxh9s09rtu6vzeru3l0asfd5ylwfqs7e0zs3hfdpt",
  "redeemScript": "52210318370919cfceb3d260081eeca3cae19f941eec321f597c48a64839178ea1e3e02103e783b8cf0474f732cc5d89cc893c25ab8a487785eb541a3ba0b26cfdd38c5c192102667b6e09a4a82b12cc8e5611373f28673f2cdd2e42b2f7e89825ec82b7f9b05453ae",
  "descriptor": "wsh(multi(2,[85ac4db2]0318370919cfceb3d260081eeca3cae19f941eec321f597c48a64839178ea1e3e0,[90060439]03e783b8cf0474f732cc5d89cc893c25ab8a487785eb541a3ba0b26cfdd38c5c19,[98725f4c]02667b6e09a4a82b12cc8e5611373f28673f2cdd2e42b2f7e89825ec82b7f9b054))#qmw7suql"
}
```

Tried using the same public keys and the order to create a multisig address in [caravan](https://unchained-capital.github.io/caravan) and got the warning that keys are not ordered.

[image: caravan-multisig]

Multisig address and Witness script returned are same for both. It changes when I order the keys in caravan:

Address:

```
 tb1q6xnkaa3sej2x580yjc5j20pcy6x0ddxxc8a9ajlvvn2de2htvvpsnp95vd
```

Witness Script:

```
522102667b6e09a4a82b12cc8e5611373f28673f2cdd2e42b2f7e89825ec82b7f9b054210318370919cfceb3d260081eeca3cae19f941eec321f597c48a64839178ea1e3e02103e783b8cf0474f732cc5d89cc893c25ab8a487785eb541a3ba0b26cfdd38c5c1953ae
```