# Difference between createmultisig and addmultisigaddress on v 0.20.0?

Tags: multi-signature, bitcoin-cli

What is difference between createmultisig and addmultisigaddress? I ran 2 methods for 2 same bitcoin address on bitcoin-cli but gives different addresses as multisig to me. the results are as follows:

````
>  bitcoin-cli -testnet createmultisig 2 "[\"03f47a5115cd9e5e21b94136db90e2e3d6ac7e40396d8e62f73df3fd3fcfb3f214\",\"0395ad430034c1761bbe9b4dfd784fb06229970d54016a7e090fc6ceb3814611b5\"]"
RESULT:
{
  "address": "**2Mt1jgrBoojAHbJS5zGJTZnx4TFktUCCNxu**",
  "redeemScript": "522103f47a5115cd9e5e21b94136db90e2e3d6ac7e40396d8e62f73df3fd3fcfb3f214210395ad430034c1761bbe9b4dfd784fb06229970d54016a7e090fc6ceb3814611b552ae",
  "descriptor": "sh(multi(2,03f47a5115cd9e5e21b94136db90e2e3d6ac7e40396d8e62f73df3fd3fcfb3f214,0395ad430034c1761bbe9b4dfd784fb06229970d54016a7e090fc6ceb3814611b5))#6nexfs8d"
} ```
````

```
> bitcoin-cli -testnet addmultisigaddress 2 "[\"2NEy9um4CpWerPeaEhPa3TckNYWnh58yDXN\",\"2Mxr2oaph8iapbnbL1MSEvfZH8EQaXYuhAy\"]"

RESULT: 
 {
  "address": "**tb1qjyvx2kwl4kq2cypj5zawhw5gpwxmphxe487z3hxj9m36ux8tylpszpazsu**",
  "redeemScript": "522103f47a5115cd9e5e21b94136db90e2e3d6ac7e40396d8e62f73df3fd3fcfb3f214210395ad430034c1761bbe9b4dfd784fb06229970d54016a7e090fc6ceb3814611b552ae",
  "descriptor": "wsh(multi(2,[a025344d/0'/0'/0']03f47a5115cd9e5e21b94136db90e2e3d6ac7e40396d8e62f73df3fd3fcfb3f214,[a025344d/0'/0'/1']0395ad430034c1761bbe9b4dfd784fb06229970d54016a7e090fc6ceb3814611b5))#gmdd9d2p"
}
```

why those addresses is different?

thank you

Comment: Try running this as first command: `bitcoin-cli -testnet createmultisig 2 "[\"03f47a5115cd9e5e21b94136db90e2e3d6ac7e40396d8e62f73df3fd3fcfb3f214\",\"0395ad430034c1761bbe9b4dfd784fb06229970d54016a7e090fc6ceb3814611b5\"]" "bech32"`

Answer (score 0):

If solution suggested in the comment resolved your problem it's related to `address_type` in both RPC commands. It is *legacy* by default for [createmultisig](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.20.0/rpc/util/createmultisig/) and set by `-addresstype` in *bitcoin.conf* for [addmultisigaddress](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.20.0/rpc/wallet/addmultisigaddress/)

You have used public keys in first command and addresses in second so I am not sure if the addresses are for same keys and in the same order.

Please refer to this question for order of keys: [Is the `addmultisignature` API call dependent on order of public keys in the array? Or is it lexicographically sorted?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/99213/is-the-addmultisignature-api-call-dependent-on-order-of-public-keys-in-the-arr/)